# Find all real frequencies $\omega$ such that $\det(C(j\omega I-A)^{-1}B)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

Given $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$,$B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $C\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ such that $\det(j\omega I-A)\neq0$, find all real frequencies $\omega$ such that

$$\det(C(j\omega I-A)^{-1}B)=0.$$

Here $j=\sqrt{-1}$ and $I$ is an identity matrix of an appropriate size.

---

If $m=n$, then

\begin{align}
\det(C(j\omega I-A)^{-1}B)=\det(BC(j\omega I-A)^{-1})=\det(BC)\det(j\omega I-A)^{-1}=0.
\end{align}
Since $\det(j\omega I-A)^{-1}\neq0$, we get $\det(BC)=0$ which doesn't depent on $\omega$, thus

if $\det(BC)=0$, then
$$\det(C(j\omega I-A)^{-1}B)=0\text{ for any }\omega\in(-\infty,+\infty),$$

else if $\det(BC)\neq0$, then

$$\det(C(j\omega I-A)^{-1}B)=0\text{ for any }\omega\in\{\emptyset\}.$$

If $m\neq n$, we don't have $\det(C(j\omega I-A)^{-1}B)=\det(BC(j\omega I-A)^{-1})$, thus I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Are the matrices mentioned purely symbols or are values attached to them? If they are purely symbols, then please get this question migrated to [math.SE] where you are more likely to get an answer.  However, I think that an analytic solution doesn't exist for the given amount of information as the underlying equation is that of solving for the roots of a polynomial and a general analytic solution doesn't exist for higher order polynomials.

Comment: \$\det( C (\dots) B)\$ is a polynomial of order \$n\$. AFAIK, there is no general formula for roots of an arbitrary polynomial of high order.

Comment: So if someone gives me matrices \$A,B,C\$, I want to be able to tell them the frequencies \$\omega\$ which will make \$\det(C(j\omega I-A)^{-1}B)=0\$.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to calculate is also called the [transmission zeros](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-241j-dynamic-systems-and-control-spring-2011/readings/MIT6_241JS11_chap27.pdf) (although, you are limiting to the ones that only have zero real part). These can also be calculated using the following [generalized eigenvalue problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem). When also including the feedthrough matrix $D$ then this problem can be written as

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ C & D
\end{bmatrix} v = \lambda
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} v,
$$

with $(A,B,C,D)$ the matrices associated with the following linear time invariant state space model

\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) &= A\,x(t) + B\,u(t), \\
y(t) &= C\,x(t) + D\,u(t),
\end{align}

which has the associated transfer function

$$
G(s) = C \left(s\,I - A\right)^{-1} B + D.
$$

However, if you prefer to you can also just set $D=0$, but I thought I would try to generalize my answer slightly.

When solving for $\lambda$, the generalized eigenvalue problem is equivalent to

$$
\det\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
A - \lambda\,I & B \\ C & D
\end{bmatrix}
\right) = 0. \tag{1}
$$

With the help of the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) the matrix inside the determinant can also be written as

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A - \lambda\,I & B \\ C & D
\end{bmatrix} = 
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\ C \left(A - \lambda\,I\right)^{-1} & I
\end{bmatrix}
}_{U}
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
A - \lambda\,I & 0 \\ 0 & C\left(\lambda\,I - A\right)^{-1}B+D
\end{bmatrix}
}_{M}
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
I & \left(A - \lambda\,I\right)^{-1}B \\ 0 & I
\end{bmatrix}
}_{V}.
$$

For $\lambda$ not an eigenvalue of $A$ the matrices $U$ and $V$ are well defined, square and always full rank (due to the block triangular structure and the identity matrices along the diagonal). So the only way for $(1)$ to be true requires that $\det(M) = 0$ and because of the block diagonal structure of $M$ this is satisfied for $\det(C\left(\lambda\,I - A\right)^{-1}B+D) = 0$.

As a side note I haven't really found a justification why the eigenvalues of $A$ also don't solve $(1)$, since the structure of $M$ would imply so. Probably the interaction with the singularities in $U$ and $V$ negates this, but I might be wrong. But this still hopefully illustrates that solving $(1)$ does finds $\lambda$ such that $\det(C\left(\lambda\,I - A\right)^{-1}B+D) = 0$. And to find solution to your question, with only $\lambda = j\,\omega$, one should then only consider the solutions to $(1)$ for $\lambda$ which have zero real part.