# Rank and generalized eigenvalues problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let we define matrices with complex entries $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, $B \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m}$, $C \in \mathbb{C}^{p \times n}$ and $D \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times p}$ and a matrix $\Lambda$ given by block matrix $\begin{pmatrix} sI-A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix}$. Let us assume that, for some $\{\lambda_c\} \subset \lambda(A)$, the rank of block-row pencil $E(s)$ given by matrix $\begin{pmatrix} sI - A & B \end{pmatrix}$ is lesser than $n$ as well as some $\{\lambda_o\} \subset \lambda(A)$, rank of block-column pencil $G(s)$ given by matrix $\begin{pmatrix} sI - A \\ C \end{pmatrix}$ is lesser than $n$. Can we say that the element $\mu \in \{\lambda_c\} \cup \{\lambda_o\}$ solve the generalized eigenvalue problem $\Lambda(\mu) v = 0$?

$
\mbox{rank} \, \Lambda = 
\mbox{rank}\begin{pmatrix}
E \\
F
\end{pmatrix} = 
\mbox{rank}\begin{pmatrix}
G & H
\end{pmatrix}
$

Comment: What are $G$ and $E$ and $F$ and $H$?

Comment: I edited to improve comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E(s)$ (that I assume, are the first $n$ rows of $\Lambda$) is not full rank, then automatically $\Lambda(s)$ cannot be full rank. This is because for every set of $2n$ linearly independent vectors, every subset is still independent.

The same applies for $G(s)$